# nestJs httpService.get request in @Interval has no reaction

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, nestjs, httpservice

I have a service with HttpService injected and start request with @Interval(20000). In interval function I do a request to another server with this.http.get(...) but I see no reaction, wether a request nor an exception. I see only console log "handleInterval"!
What is wrong?

```
 :
import {HttpException, HttpService, Injectable} from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private readonly http: HttpService) {}

  @Interval(20000)
  handleInterval() {
    console.log('handleInterval');
    let response = this.http.get('192.168.0.162:8081/diag.fhtml', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).pipe(
        map(res => {
          console.log('received data');
          return res.data;
        }),
        catchError(e => {
          console.error(e);
          throw new HttpException(e.response.data, e.response.status);
        }));
  }
 :
 :
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest's `HttpService`  makes use of `RxJS` Observables. To trigger the request, you need to add `.subscribe()` **or** make the function `async` and add `.toPromise()`.